# shopify how to get current option value

Tags: javascript, shopify

This is the backend coding for the display of data.

```
<div class="select clearfix"{% if hide_default_title %} style="display:none"{% endif %}>
                <select id="product-select" name="id">
                  {% for variant in product.variants %}
                  <option value="{{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.title }} - {{ variant.price | money }}</option>
                  {% endfor %}
                </select>
              </div>

              {% if settings.display_quantity_dropdown %}
              <div class="selector-wrapper">
                <label>Quantity</label>
                <input id="quantity" type="text" name="quantity" value="1"  min="1" class="tc item-quantity" />
              </div>
              {% endif %}

              <div class="purchase-section{% if product.variants.size > 1 %} multiple{% endif %}">
                <div class="purchase">
                  {% unless product.available %}
                  <p>Sold Out</p>
                  {% else %}
```

The html result for this is

```
          <option value="720021189">Blue / Medium / V-Neck - $ 19.99</option>

          <option value="720021193">green / Large / V-Neck - $ 25.00</option>

          <option value="720021197">red / XL / V-Neck - $ 25.00</option>

        </select>
      </div>
```

so my problem is when i choose the produce the option value must be given to onlink as i mentioned below.But it always take the first value which 720021189.Can anybody help me out?

```
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="add-to-cart" onclick="fastcart({{product.variants.first.price}},1)"><span></span>Buy it now</a>
```

Result for this is always

Buy it now

I need to change that value dynamically according to option selection not only fixed on the same value. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use plain javascript to get the value.

```
var productSelect = document.getElementById('product-select');
var variantId = productSelect.options[productSelect.selectedIndex].value;
```

Then pass it to your fastcart() function.

EDIT:

If you want to do it "dynamically" just wrap the above code in a function (ex: getSelectedValue) and use the onchange event on your select.

```
<select id="product-select" name="id" onchange="getSelectedValue()">
```

You can also use jQuery (probably already loaded in your theme) and do all of this in a single line of code.